# How can i create a custom ListView with my xml layout file?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, firebase

[Java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ047.png)

[list view  layout #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQMkI.png)

How can i insert change the graphics of my  ListView adding this layout file  to my list view? What should i write in my java code for making each row of my ListView just like my layout file. Thank you all guys !!

Comment: Question is little bit cofusing but if I understood right you have to create a custom adapter and inflate your layout.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry for my misunderstanding

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You want a custom layout for your ListView items?

Comment: You can find many examples on the internet how to implement `ListView` with custom adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to create the xml for the custom row you want(custom_row.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/text" /> </LinearLayout>
```

Then you need to create your custom adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<String> textArray;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public RutinaAdapter(Context context, List<String> textarray) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.textArray = textarray;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return textArray.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return textArray.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewGroup vg;

    if (convertView != null) {
        vg = (ViewGroup) convertView;
    } else {
        vg = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
    }

    String text = textArray.get(position);

    final TextView text = ((TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.text));

    return vg;
} }
```

Then you need to add the adapter to the ListView:

```
list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);  
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(),textArray);
list.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Add info to you textArray, and notify the adapter data changed, and thats it.